# Difference between font size on mobile compared to desktop

Tags: html, css, font-size

Im creating a website using html and css but I was just wondering whether anyone knows the difference between text sizes on all platforms.

If i create a font-size as 20px on desktop, on mobile that would look very small and you wouldnt be able to read it so is font size usually bigger on a mobile device?

Answer (score 4):

Without the correct `meta` tag, yes the text would be super small.

> ...is font size usually bigger on a mobile device?

No, not typically. As in, most sites that provide a responsive version do not tell their `font-size` to be 80px (or whatever) so the text is not super tiny.

Mobile devices have what is known as a ***device width***. This *device width* usually packs multiple device pixels per CSS pixel. I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 that has a device pixel to CSS pixel ratio of 4:1. That means there are 4 device pixels per CSS pixel. The resolution (device pixels) of this device is 1440 x 2560, but the CSS pixel resolution is 360 x 640.

When developing a site on a desktop computer and you tell an element to be 100px wide, you're actually using CSS pixels. You probably thought it was a device pixel (as I once did) because almost all desktop monitors have a device pixel to CSS pixel ratio of 1:1.

When using a responsive meta tag, like the one below, and you tell an element to be 300px wide it will take up most of the screen's width because the element will be painted on a 360 CSS pixel wide canvas, not 1440 device pixel wide canvas (which is what happens without the proper `meta` tag and gives the appearance of a site being *"zoomed out"* on a mobile device).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Helpful links:

- [Quirks Mode, A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)
- [WebPlatform Docs, Understanding CSS Units](https://www.webplatform.org/docs/tutorials/understanding-css-units/)
- [mydevice.io](http://mydevice.io/) - displays current device settings.
- [mydevice.io/devices](http://mydevice.io/devices/)

Hopefully everything makes sense, I tried to keep it *"simple."*

Answer (score 1):

You are right.
Have a look at EM (element units) and REM (relative element units) for sizing elements. Also adding the following code to your header might solve your problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```